# Is there any way to using Pattern and Matcher class, parse php file variable or array in java desktop application?

Tags: java, php

I have one desktop application in which I want to read php file using IO class.  And then parse php variable/array on my java class.  Is there any pattern that is used in java using Pattern and Matcher  class to extract php variable?

Comment: can you please provide example which you want to parse in java.

Comment: @simmant As far as I can understand there are variables declared in a php file which should be extracted in Java. Not sure if I'm right.

Comment: @JimmyT. if they want that then its very easy to parse in java using StringTokenizer